# For TF 2, how to distribute a pretrained model across multiple nodes?

Tags: tensorflow, huggingface-transformers

When I read the original TF paper, I was told that

> Dataflow simplifies distributed execution, because it makes
> communication between subcomputations explicit. It enables the same
> TensorFlow program to be deployed to a cluster of GPUs for training, a
> cluster of TPUs for serving, and a cellphone for mobile inference.
> Each operation resides on a particular device, such as a CPU or GPU in
> a particular task. A device is responsible for executing a kernel for
> each operation assigned to it. (...) The TensorFlow runtime places
> operations on devices, subject to implicit or explicit constraints in
> the graph. The placement algorithm computes a feasible set of devices
> for each operation, calculates the sets of operations that must be
> colocated, and selects a satisfying device for each colocation group.

I had never need more than one device. But now large models are all the rage, and a lot of competition is about just getting the weights of a pretrained model and run them **for inference**. So I want cluster all the GPUs of a room so they could be useful for this to just run a LLM, it could be an ad-hoc graph, a keras model or a HuggingFace transformer.

So, how is it done? I guess one still needs to configure a cluster description and, if such option is available still in 2.x, launch an script in each machine to join them into a cluster. And then somehow launch a master script in some other machine that loads the model, deploys its graph across the cluster, and runs it.

What I hope is to find a recipe such as:
What I was looking for was a recipe such as:

- Load or build the model.
- From the model, obtain the graph.
- For each node, launch a server for all the devices it manages, or allows allocation.
- For the graph,

  - loop manually across, using tf.device() or something similar to
    allocate each operation to a device.
  - or, alternatively, give to tf a list of all the target devices and let it to allocate as it needs.
- execute inference.

Comment: Have a look at the tf's [Distribute API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/distribute) and the distributed training official [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/distributed_training?hl=en)

Comment: @LucaAnzalone it seems that it always copy the full model in each node, does it? Perhaps one could create an strategy to deploy the graph in v1 style.

Comment: The `MirroredStrategy` replicates the models across all nodes, but there is also the [ParameterServerStrategy](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/distribute/parameter_server_training?hl=en) that also supports *variable sharding* (see the homonym page section) to distribute the computation (and not only the data) across your cluster by means of a central parameter server.

Comment: @LucaAnzalone perhaps it is a bug in the documentation then? the first line says  **is a common data-parallel method** so I guessed it was not model parallel. Do you think it is mixed, data and model?

Comment: It seems that it can be configured as a mixed strategy (data + model), it says: "Variable sharding may be useful to distribute the network load [...]. It is also useful to distribute computation and storage [...] across multiple parameter servers." Did you give a look at the two training examples ("training with model.fit" and "custom training loop")?

Comment: @LucaAnzalone I will test, but I was under the impression, looking the cluster config json, that the sharding was only for the parameter servers, not the workers.

Comment: I guess you're right. So, what if having two or more parameter servers? If it's reasonable to do that you would be able to distribute the model too.

Comment: @LucaAnzalone a point that puzzles me is that if it were easy, we should not have the current buzz about downsizing models to 4bits to fit them in consumer hardware,

Comment: Well, you can manually split a model (or graph) in more pieces by using the device scope, i.e. `with tf.device(...): stuff`. But I don't know if you can do that on distributed (not local) GPUs, and how tf handles that. In alternative, you can try [ray](https://github.com/ray-project/ray).